# Scanf into double pointer

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, double-pointer

Can you get input in double pointer after scanf? Is this wrong? I have malloced the array in the main function.

````
void input(int **array, int x, int y){
        int s,t;

        printf("array element:\n");
        for(s = 0; s < x; s++){
                for(t = 0; t < y; t++){
                       scanf("%d", array[s][t]);
                }
        }
} ```
````

Comment: `**array` it is not the array

Comment: Yes, but `array[s][t]` is an `int`, and `scanf` needs the address of the object, not the object itself, so use `&array[s][t]` (an `int *`).

Comment: This is just a typo, you're missing `&`.

Comment: Compile with `gcc -Wall -Wextra` and you'll see the error.

Comment: What exactly did you `malloc`? If it was space for a single 2D array of `int`, then the `int **array` parameter will be incompatible with it. It wants a (pointer to first element of an) array of `int *`, with each `int *` pointing to an array of `int`.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli: It does not appear to be a typographical error. It appears to be a conceptual error. The fact that correct code can be obtained by inserting a single character does not mean the errant code was caused by failing to type an intended character rather than by a lack of understanding by the author.

Comment: @IanAbbott: That is not relevant; the question does not complain of a compiler reporting a type mismatch in calling the function, and `&array[s][t]` would serve in the `scanf` inside the function regardless of whether the proper parameter type were `int **` or `int (*)[dimension]`.

Answer (score 0):

`scanf` must be passed the address of the object to be written to. If you want to scan a value into `array[s][t]`, you must pass its address, `&array[s][t]`. Replace `scanf("%d", array[s][t]);` with `scanf("%d", &array[s][t]);`.